# What accomplishments count towards the Legendary Defender achievement?

Tags: dungeon-defenders

The description says "You have earned every Dungeon Defenders Accomplishment! Trendy salutes you!". What counts as "every accomplishment" for the purpose of this, and is any of it in the DLC or can I complete with the base game?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All of it should be completable using the base game, for a full list of the achievements required refer to the [Dungeon Defenders Wiki](http://dungeondefenders.wikia.com/wiki/Legendary_Defender)

It basically comprises out of:

1. Finishing all levels
2. Finishing all challenges
3. Getting to certain wave levels on survival
4. Getting all the level-up achievements
5. Earn certain awards on a certain amount of levels.
6. Get loads of mana

Comment: The only really tough one here seems like "Catch 'em All" :S I also didn't realize Accomplishments was refering to achievements.